# Spring Issues: Error creating beans and Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

So i'm trying to learn spring and i've been reading a lot of tutorials and trying copying some code from a project that I have in a flash drive.

I already set up tomcat and it works find but i'm still having some problems here.
The thing is I can normally access a controller's action from my browser without a problem, but when I started adding annotations and ContextLoaderListener it gave me a 404 status all the time. I don't know what I did, but by tweaking some things around, my browser at least tries to reach the controller again. But throws a huge error log which I will share at the end of this post.

These are my dependencies:

> - junit 4.12
> - spring-webmvc 4.1.6.RELEASE
> - spring-context 4.1.6.RELEASE
> - spring-web 4.1.6.RELEASE
> - spring-beans 4.1.6.RELEASE
> - spring-data-jpa 1.8.0.RELEASE
> - spring-jdbc 4.1.6.RELEASE
> - mysql-connector-java 5.1.35
> - jstl 1.2
> - javax.servlet-api 3.1.0 (scope provided)
> - javax.servlet.jsp-api 3.1.0 (scope provided)
> - jackson-databind 2.5.4
> - jackson-core 2.5.4
> - jackson-core-asl 1.9.13
> - jackson-datatype-hibernate4 2.5.4
> - hibernate-annotations 3.5.6-Final
> - hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0.Final
> - hibernate-entitymanager 4.3.10.Final
> - jsondoc-core 1.1.15
> - jsondoc-springmvc 1.1.15
> - jsondoc-ui-webjar 1.1.15
> - commons-logging 1.2
> - commons-logging-api 1.1
> - commons-dbcp 1.4

My build plugins are:

> - maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 (source and target 1.8)
> - maven-war-plugin 2.4

**My web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:WEB-INF/application-context.xml
        classpath*:WEB-INF/persistence-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**My mvc-dispatcher-servlet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ve" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="com.ve.main.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="documentationController" class="org.jsondoc.springmvc.controller.JSONDocController">
    <constructor-arg name="version" value="1.0"/>
    <constructor-arg name="basePath" value="http://localhost:4848/spring2"/>
    <constructor-arg name="packages">
    <list>
    <value>com.ve</value>
    </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**My application-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ve" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
</context:component-scan>
```

**My persistence-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database" />
    <property name="username" value="my_actual_db_user" />
    <property name="password" value="my_actual_db_password" />
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.ve" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

And just for information i will also quote my classes code and my project structure

**StockController**

```
package com.ve.common.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.ve.common.service.StockService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/stock")
public class StockController {

    @Autowired
    private StockService stockService;

    public StockController(){}

    @RequestMapping(value="/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json","application/xml"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String findAllStocks(){
        return "stocks";
    }
}
```

**StockService**

```
package com.ve.common.service;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.ve.common.model.Stock;
import com.ve.common.repo.StockRepository;

@Service
public class StockService {

    @Autowired
    private StockRepository stockRepository;

    StockService(){}

    List<Stock> findStock(){
        return (List<Stock>) stockRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**StockRepository**

```
package com.ve.common.repo;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.ve.common.model.Stock;

@Repository
public interface StockRepository extends CrudRepository<Stock, Integer> {

    List<Stock> findByStockName(String stockName);

    Stock findByStockId(Integer stockId);
}
```

My model is a basic Entity class that implements Serializable (created by JPA tools).
Now this is my project structure, I'm sorry I couldn't make the image smaller (i'm in a ruch at the moment).
[image: Project Structure]

And here is a quote of that huge error i get in my browser when i access "http://localhost:4848/spring2/api/welcome/hi" or "http://localhost:4848/spring2/api/stock/list"

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw
>   exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   mvc-dispatcher threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'stockController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.ve.common.service.StockService
>   com.ve.common.controller.StockController.stockService; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ve.common.service.StockService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.ve.common.service.StockService
>   com.ve.common.controller.StockController.stockService; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ve.common.service.StockService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [com.ve.common.service.StockService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I apologize for the excessive code blocking and blockquoting, but I think the more information I provide, the better help I can get. And I thank in advance whoever can give me a hand.

Comment: I've been messing around with my java code and I narrowed my problem down to @Autowired... When i remove Autowired classes and i can access my controller's methods from my browser, however I can't really do anything unless i only want to return string to the view. When i call my service's methods from my controller without autowiring i get a **"HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"**

Comment: It's because your StockService is not set. When you add autowired the spring tries to inject the StockService but it cannot find it - so your spring contexts are not loaded as you would expect. Looks like only your dispatcher servlet is loaded, but not the application/persistence context. Try to figure out what you're missing to get all the contexts loaded

Comment: Checkout my solution. May it helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry guys but these solutions still don't work for me. The thing is I've seen projects work with code like mine. Beans are created automatically without adding @Bean to the java code and without manually adding each bean to the xml. And I've tried those options and I get the same error anyway.

Comment: I have always found it easier to set spring logs to debug and then inspect logs in case of any start up failure. In this case it is clear from the start up logs that the context has not been loaded

Answer (score 7):

> org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: No qualifying bean of type [com.ve.common.service.**StockService**]

The error itself says that **SpringContainer doesn't find the bean with name** `StockService`. So either you *create bean in `applicationContext.xml` file or declare bean with the [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation*.

**[@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) :** This annotation allows you to not explicitly declaring your bean in `applicationContext.xml`. But you have to create bean of class you want to autowire using [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation & add `<context:conponent-scan>` in `XML` to know the bean is being created using [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation.

**Declaring Bean :** To declare bean annotate the method with [`@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) annotation just like

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public StockService stockService() {
        return new StockServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to declaring bean in the `applicationContext.xml`

```
<beans>
    <bean name="stockService" class="com.ve.common.service.StockServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

**OR**

If you want to use [`@Autowired`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotation in a bean class then must first have to enable annotation in spring using below configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

or

```
<bean class ="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

**For More Info :**

1. [Spring beans autowiring](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/08/spring-beans-autowiring-concepts/)
2. [@Bean - Declaring a bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Or put an @Service above your service class and add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.ve.common.service"/>` to your spring config.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with your web.xml. Please change the contextconfiglocation to the following

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
       WEB-INF/application-context.xml
       WEB-INF/persistence-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

You have used `classpath*:WEB-INF/application-context.xml`.WEB-INF/ path is not in the classpath(only WEB-INF/classes is) the context loader is not able to find the 2 context files.

Comment: That's how i first tried it. When i do that two things happen: 1. The application can't find those files, and 2. I get a 404 status because i can't even reach the controller.